# Help With sublimeText on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, sublime-text

This is the error that appears when I try to update my system!

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_sublime-text-3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages - open (13: permission denied), E:it wasn't possible to open the archive 
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_sublime-text-3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages - open (13: Permission Denied)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit.

Comment: What is the command you issued to update? Did you run it using `sudo`?

Comment: The error `Permission Denied` suggests you didn't have the rights to update sublime. Try using `sudo` before your command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What you have to do is reinstall ubuntu 16.04.01 by erasing ubuntu 16.04 and back up all your data, and programs for that arent that hard to find. But if u mainly use it to program like me, then back up all your files on at least on a 4-16 GB flashdrive. Afterwards, everything worked for me, except that you have to reinstall all your applications. If this isn't an option, then try opening up the terminal and type "sudo apt-get upgrade" and when it says that it doesnt work, you can see the error there in the code, and it might even help you out with a little suggestion. My friends laptop with ubuntu also couldnt update, so when he typed "sudo apt-get upgrade" an error message popped up saying "try -f" and when he applied it to "sudo apt-get upgrade" it worked but dont try this because the process might not be the same for you. Btw are you an administrator? If you are doing this from another User account on the same OS as another user, then chances are that this is failing because your user account doesnt have any administrator privileges.

Comment: Reinstall is IMHO an overkill for this problem. `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` looks much more like a correct solution.

Comment: [Reinstall the whole system is a bad answer.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11710/lets-not-do-i-dont-know-how-to-fix-your-problem-so-just-reinstall)